# shell script for extracting specfic date log

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, scripting

I have to extract particular date's log from any application log. what we generally do

1. vi app.log
2. /date (searching)
3. .= (position where date found)
4. G(last line)
5. first_line,Last_line w filname.log (to generate log file with particular date)

I made small script but I think My logic is not correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p " enter the App name" : app
read =p " enter the Date in this Format 10 Jan 20:01:00" : date
FILE=/logs/$app.log

# Check if $app exists or not
if test ! -f "$app" /logs
then
    echo "Error - $app not found."
else

    First_line=$(cat $FILE | grep $date | .=)
    Second_line=$(tail -1 $FILE | .=)
    vi $FILE | $First_line, $Second_line w $app.txt
fi
```

---

Comment: 1. read =p " enter the Date in this Format 10 Jan 20:01:00" : date ...... 2 First_line=$(cat $FILE | grep $date | .=)

Comment: Using `vim` when `sed` or similar would do the job makes life unnecessarily hard. For example, `sed -n '/2015-01-02/,$p' app.log` would print all the lines from the first line containing 2nd January 2015 to the end of the file.  If your date format is different, modify the search pattern accordingly.  Note that if you get specific with the time, you may never have a record (for example, if you search for 20:01:00, but the log records go from 20:00:59 to 20:01:01 (nothing mentions 20:01:00), then you won't see anything. For that, you need 'if date greater than start date', but that is trickier.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the line

```
if test ! -f "$app" /logs
```

You seperated "$app" and /logs with a space; `test -f` expects one parameter, so it should be:

```
if test ! -f "$app"/logs
```

To get the log starting from the date given to the current end of the file, You should use `sed` (meaning "stream editor"), which is designed for noninteractive editing of files:

```
sed -n '/'$date'/,$ p' $app.log >$app.txt
```

The parameter `-n` is to only output, what matched and not the whole file.

Here I am telling `sed` to extract everything between two regular expressions, the first one, being the `$date` parameter given, the second one meaning "end of file". You could change this easily to extract all logs for one specific day or whatever.

As something seems to be unclear I am adding a complete example:
I have an apache log file, where the date logged looks like this `[01/Apr/2015:22:31:21 +0200]`.

So I can do:

```
export date="01\/Apr\/2015"
```

It is important to note that I am escaping the slashes here, as they are going into a regex. This has to be done with everything that has some special meaning inside regexes too.

Then I can do:

```
sed -n '/'$date'/,$ p' myaccess.log
```

and I get everything logged for the 1st of April until the end of the file.

Comment: no I want log from from fist line to last line of log.. like log of 12 march .. so script will extract whole day log, this command "first_line,Last_line w filname.log" extract whole log, but after opening file in Vi or vim editor

Comment: but it will fail we get multiplication error.. as you said it will only extract line which start with that particular date, therefore SED command not good to use in this case :( ... did you find any logic error the script I made ... ? its not working

Comment: The line above should replace, what is in your `else` case. Did you do this?

Comment: I am getting this error [t3718 logs]$ ./testing_script 
 enter the App name : esqm
 enter the Date in this Format ---- '10 Jan 20:01:00' : Mar 29 04:49:19
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated address regex
updating: esqm.txt (stored 0%)
[t3718 logs]$

Comment: in this sed -n '/'$date'/,$ p' $app.log >$app.txt .. if use sed -n '/$date/,$ p' $app.log >$app.txt it generate empty file and if I use the code you mention m getting error

Answer (score 0):

You could pass commands to `vi` from your script with a here document, if your task is as mechanical as you describe.

I'm talking about something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p " enter the App name" : app
read =p " enter the Date in this Format 10 Jan 20:01:00" : date
FILE=/logs/$app.log

# Check if $app exists or not
if test ! -f "$app" /logs
then
    echo "Error - $app not found."
else
    vi $FILE <<-_EOF_
          /date
          .=
          G
          first_line,Last_line w filname.log
          etc, etc
    _EOF_
fi
```

I just wrote this as an idea that you mighr find fun to explore. I know the code will not work.

Comment: Note to readers: there must be **tab characters**, not spaces, before the ending word `_EOF_`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk:

```
awk -v date="$date" '$0 ~ date {p=1} p' file.in > file.out
```

That will start printing lines when the date is first seen, until the end of the line.